# Querying the monthly average population

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called `patients`. I'm trying to query the Monthly Average Daily Patients. For example, if I query today:

`select count(*) from patients where active=1`

It returns:

```
-----------
213

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Mathematically, I would need to get the count per day, then divide by the number of days in the month.

If I want to get the average daily count of active patients per month, how would I do this?

edit:

Some sample data showing a `Patient ID` and their `creation_date`.

```
Patient ID  creation_date
----------- -----------------------
48          2011-11-16 08:59:34.000
55          2011-11-16 09:09:20.000
82          2011-11-16 09:32:48.000
110         2011-11-16 09:42:38.000
111         2011-11-16 09:42:53.000
123         2011-11-16 09:47:01.000
138         2011-11-16 09:58:02.000
188         2011-11-16 10:20:03.000
225         2011-11-16 10:32:53.000
231         2011-11-16 10:34:48.000
241         2011-11-16 10:38:13.000
259         2011-11-16 10:44:35.000
377         2011-12-17 10:26:21.000
536         2012-02-02 16:10:57.000
551         2012-02-05 11:42:22.000
591         2012-02-12 12:14:57.000
```

My desired results would be something like:

```
Month                          Month Number Year        ADP
------------------------------ ------------ ----------- -----------
November                       11           2011        240
December                       12           2011        280
January                        1            2012        220
February                       2            2012        225
March                          3            2012        241
April                          4            2012        212
May                            5            2012        210
```

EDIT: it seems like the answers submitted are giving me an average daily count for NEW patients, which is a smaller number. I need the average daily count for the TOTAL population.

EDIT: I've learned that patient status tracking are tracked in a table called `patient_booking_data` with a column called `release`. This might help. Below is sample data from this table:

```
id          pid         booking_no                       date                    release                 active facility date_created            temporary temporary_no
----------- ----------- -------------------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ------ -------- ----------------------- --------- --------------------------------
1           1           12345                            2011-11-03 00:00:00.000 2011-11-15 10:45:00.000 0      11535    2011-11-03 12:45:36.000 0         NULL
2           2           7890                             2011-11-14 12:00:00.000 2011-11-21 07:01:00.000 1      11535    2011-11-14 08:45:33.000 0         NULL
3           3           100                              2011-11-14 09:00:00.000 2011-11-21 07:00:00.000 1      11535    2011-11-14 08:45:34.000 0         NULL
4           4           111                              2011-11-14 09:00:00.000 2011-11-21 07:01:00.000 1      11535    2011-11-14 08:45:34.000 0         NULL
5           5           12                               2011-11-14 10:20:00.000 2011-11-21 07:02:00.000 1      11535    2011-11-14 10:21:25.000 0         NULL
6           6           1234                             2011-11-14 00:00:00.000 2011-11-21 07:02:00.000 1      11535    2011-11-14 10:25:10.000 0         NULL
7           7           1123                             2011-11-14 11:14:00.000 2011-11-21 07:01:00.000 1      11535    2011-11-14 11:15:44.000 0         NULL
```

Comment: What is the name of the date field in this table? Do you need to use all days (including holidays) to get the average?

Comment: Is there a timeline associated with each patient that details the start and end date of his or her stay? If not and you only have your boolean `active` column without history data you are out of luck.

Comment: Please post some sample data and desired output

Comment: @shahkalpesh, there is a `creation_date` field.

Comment: @Quassnoi, I've added sample data and desired output.

Comment: Looks like there is no way to tell **when** a patient became inactive.    If that is true, there is not enough data to calculate the total number of patients on a day.

Comment: @Andomar: strictly speaking, if they back up their transaction logs there is a way, though somewhat complicated. However, the comment history makes me suggest they're not archiving the xlogs :)

Comment: @Andomar, I've actually just checked. We do track when a patient has been released in our `patient_booking_data` table. Column is called `release`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  m,
        cnt * 1. / DATEDIFF(day, m, DATEADD(month, 1, m)) AS adp
FROM    (
        SELECT  DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, creation_date), 0) AS m, COUNT(*) AS cnt
        FROM    mytable
        GROUP BY
                DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, creation_date), 0)
        ) q
```

Update:

Create a table which would track changes to patients' statuses:

```
CREATE TABLE
        status
        (
        id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        patient INT NOT NULL,
        active BIT NOT NULL,
        ts DATETIME NOT NULL
        )

CREATE INDEX
        ix_status_patient_ts
ON      status (patient, ts) INCLUDE (active)
```

and record each status change to a patient.

Then run this query:

```
WITH    months (mon) AS
        (
        SELECT  '2012-01-01'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  DATEADD(month, 1, mon)
        FROM    months
        WHERE   m < '2014-12-01'
        )
SELECT  mon, COUNT(*)
FROM    patient p
CROSS JOIN
        months m
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1
                active
        FROM    status s
        WHERE   s.patient = p.id
                AND s.ts <= m.mon
        ORDER BY
                ts DESC, id DESC
        ) s
WHERE   s.active = 1
GROUP BY
        mon
```

Comment: It looks like this is returning the average new patients for each day, I'd like the TOTAL number of patients per day.

Comment: +1 and [Example at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/08198/15/0), @etm124: This shows the monthly average of total number of patients per day

Comment: @etm124: please elaborate. Is the desired output you provided in your sample supposed to originate from the data you provided? In your output there are entries for March, April, May etc which seem to be missing from the input.

Comment: @Quassnoi, the desired output is not to originate from the data I provided. 

For example, if I run `select count(*) from patients where active=1`, I return the `213` value. That is the total active patients in the system for today 2013/04/03. If I run this query tomorrow, it may go up or down a few patients, as some patients leave, or we admit new patients. 

On average, the facility is hovering ~200 active patients per day, and that is reflected in my desired output. The output that I am getting from your query looks to be just the daily new patients admitted. (1/2).

Comment: @etm124: please post some sample data and output which would originate from them.

Comment: @Quassnoi, Here is my results when running your query: http://pastebin.com/ARmczGWv

Comment: @etm124: do you record a timestamp when a patient changes their active status?

Comment: @Quassnoi, we do not. It their status is simply changed from active to inactive. Are you understanding what I am trying to convey and what results I'm trying to achieve? Sorry if I'm not being clear.

Comment: @etm124: yes I do understand. If you don't store this information then you can't get the information you want, it's lost. You should make an additional table with the patients' statuses and timestamps of their change.

Comment: If there would be a table that would track patient statuses, how would that work with your query? Thanks again.

Comment: @Quassnoi, I've actually just checked, and we do track a `release_date`.

Comment: @etm124: please post some sample data (with all relevant columns) and desired output. Calculate the output manually so that it would match your data. If you are able to do that, I'll post an explanation how to wrap it into a query.

Comment: @Quassnoi added sample data.

Comment: @etm124: now please post the desired resultset.

Comment: @Quassnoi, I'm afraid I may not understand what you are asking for. My desired result set should be the same as stated in the original question.

Comment: @etm124: your desired resultset shows 280 active patients for December, while there are only 7 records in your sample data. I'm asking that you, yourself, calculate the desired resultset for the small subset of data you provided, in order to better understand your needs.

Comment: I've used parts of your query to figure it out. Thanks @Quassnoi.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the least elegant query I've ever written, but it does give you the desired result, which is the average number of patients per days per month:

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, creation_date) AS [Month],
       DATEPART(MONTH, creation_date) AS [Month Number],
       DATEPART(YEAR, creation_date) AS Year,
       CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT) / DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(creation_date), creation_date), DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(creation_date), creation_date))) AS ADP
  FROM patients
  GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, creation_date),
       DATEPART(month, creation_date),
       DATEPART(year, creation_date),
       DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(creation_date), creation_date), DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(creation_date), creation_date)))
  ORDER BY 3, 2
```

Here it is on [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/61527/15).

Comment: It looks like this is returning the average new patients for each day, I'd like the TOTAL number of patients per day.

Comment: Your original post asks for _average daily count of active patients per month_ which this should give you - the number of daily patitents per day for the month in question.

Comment: No need to group on the `datediff` construct; you can just use `day(max(creation_date))`, since all dates will be in the same month

Comment: @Andomar thanks for that - but I think the query isn't giving the data that etm124 was asking for.  I may have misunderstood that requirement.

Comment: @MartinParkin, I have elaborated in Quassnoi's answer above. Thank yo.=u.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to answer your question:

```
SELECT YEAR(thedate), MONTH(thedate), datename(month, thedate()), AVG(cnt*1.0)
FROM (SELECT cast(creation_date as date) as thedate, count(*)  as cnt
      FROM patients
      where active = 1
      GROUP BY cast(creation_date as date)
     ) t
group by YEAR(thedate), MONTH(thedate),  datename(month, thedate())
order by 1, 2;
```

This versino assumes that you have data on each day.  A closer look at your data suggests this is not the case, this version comes close:

```
SELECT YEAR(thedate), MONTH(thedate), datename(month, thedate()),
        sum(cnt*1.0) / count(*) as average
FROM (SELECT cast(creation_date as date) as thedate, count(*)  as cnt
      FROM patients
      where active = 1
      GROUP BY cast(creation_date as date)
     ) t
group by YEAR(thedate), MONTH(thedate),  datename(month, thedate())
order by 1, 2;
```

If you really want to count the days, and you don't have a calendar table, the SQL gets a bit more complicated.  The following assumes that you have at least one record in each month (to generate the mons table):

```
with pc as (
      SELECT cast(creation_date as date) as thedate, count(*)  as cnt,
             MIN(YEAR(creation_date)*12+MONTH(creation_date)) as monnum
      FROM patients
      where active = 1
      GROUP BY cast(creation_date as date)
     ),
     mons as (
      select distinct YEAR(creation_date) as yr, MONTH(creation_date) as mon, DATENAME(month, creation_date) as monname,
             CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(creation_date)-1),creation_date),101) as FirstDay,
             CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,creation_date))),DATEADD(mm,1,creation_date)),101) as LastDay,
             YEAR(creation_date)*12+MONTH(creation_date) as monnum
      from patients
     )
SELECT mons.yr, mons.mon, mons.monname,
       (SUM(datediff(day, (case when pc.thedate < mons.FirstDay then mons.FirstDay else  pc.thedate end),
                     (case when pc.thedate > mons.LastDay then mons.LastDay else pc.thedate end)
                    ) * pc.cnt
           ) /
        SUM(datediff(day, (case when pc.thedate < mons.FirstDay then mons.FirstDay else  pc.thedate end),
                     (case when pc.thedate > mons.LastDay then mons.LastDay else pc.thedate end)
                    )
           )
       ) as avgday
FROM mons join
    (select pc.*,
             (select top 1 pc2.monnum from pc pc2 where pc2.thedate > pc.thedate order by thedate
             ) as nextmonnum
      from pc
     ) pc
     on mons.monnum between pc.monnum and pc.nextmonnum
group by mons.yr, mons.mon, mons.monname
order by 1, 2;
```

Basically, it creates a begin and end date for each patient record -- the period of time when the count will be constant because no new patients come in.  It then does a bunch of fiddling and arithmetic to count up the number of patient-days per month and the number of days in each month.  I haven't tested this, so it is susceptible to syntax errors and off-by-one errors.  I give it here as an example.

However, what you are counting is the number of currently active patients in the past months, not the number of active patients in those months.

To get the number of active patients, you need to provide the date of both "activation" and "deactivation".

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
    select  to_char(creation_date, 'mon') Month,
            to_char(creation_date, 'mm') Month_Number,
            to_char(creation_date, 'yyyy') Year,
            count(Patient_ID) / to_char(last_day(to_date(to_char(creation_date, 'yyyymm')),'DD') Avg_per_Month
       from patients 
      where active=1
   group by to_char(creation_date, 'mon'),
            to_char(creation_date, 'mm'),
            to_char(creation_date, 'yyyy'),
            to_char(last_day(to_date(to_char(creation_date, 'yyyymm')),'DD')
```

the following code returns the number of days for a given month:

```
to_char(last_day(to_date(to_char(creation_date, 'yyyymm')),'DD')
```

Comment: I'm afraid the question is for SQL Server, not Oracle :)

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the first day of a month with:

```
dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @date), 0)
```

And the first day of the next month with:

```
dateadd(month, 1 + datediff(month, 0, @date), 0)
```

The number of days in a month is the difference between the two.  Applied to your question this becomes:

```
select  datepart(year, creation_date) as Year
,       datepart(month, creation_date) as Month
,       1.0 * count(*) / datediff(day,
            dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, min(creation_date)), 0),
            dateadd(month, 1+datediff(month, 0, min(creation_date)), 0))
            as DailyAverage
from    Table1
group by
        datepart(year, creation_date)
,       datepart(month, creation_date)
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/08198/13/0)